# Ionic 2 / Angular: Pass data to tab component

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a tab layout in my Ionic 2 app and I'd like the parent, Tab, component to listen for an event from one of the child views.  Here's what I have:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-basic" (calculated_cost)="doIt()">
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Profile" [root]="profilePage" (calculated_cost)="doIt()"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Weigh Ins" [root]="weighinsPage"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Finance" [root]="financePage"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Images" [root]="imagePage" ></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

doIt() {
  console.log("Something happened!");
}
```

In the `profilePage` I have an `EventEmitter`:

```
@Output() calculated_cost: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

and my `profilePage` component calls:

```
constructor() {
    this.calcCost()
}

calcCost() {
    this.calculated_cost.emit('foo')
}
```

and I would've thought the `doIt()` function in the tab component would've fired the `console.log("Something happened!")` but I don't see anything.  I'm new to component communication so an explanation will help a lot!

Comment: Your event is emitted on the <ion-tab> and not on your `profilePage` component... so unless your code looks like this: `<profile-page (calculated_cost)="doIt()"></profile-page>`. Consider using a service/provider

Comment: Is there a way to listen to events from the `<ion-tab>`?

Comment: did you find any solution around it?

Comment: ended up using a service and avoided events like that